# How do I change the default development server URL (i.e. http://127.0.0.1:8000) to http://127.0.0.1:8000/user in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

Helle techies, Whenever I start the server using `php artisan serve` command the development http://127.0.0.1:8000 URL. But I want that when I start the server on my machine the server starts at http://127.0.0.1:8000/user URL.

Comment: Hi Ghulam, you could achieve this using Route Prefixes https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-group-prefixes?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can use Route Prefixes, anything inside the route prefix will be added to the URL:

```
Route::prefix('user')->group(function () {
    // home
    Route::get("/", [HomeController::class, "index"]);
    
    ... (the rest of your routes) 
});
```

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-group-prefixes

Comment: Surely it will work. But I want that the server starts at this URL http://127.0.0.1:8000/user
whenever I write `php artisan serve`. The method you define is manually written of URL.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could take a look on this one
[change default dev server url](https://gist.github.com/ejlocop/2e81cd3134fbc6b7858f28eb6fd4a60f).

Or you can try redirecting the route on start when a user visits that route.
Because I knew that the php artisan serve command has --host && --port flags only to set the dev url.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect('/user');
});
```